# Using HTML5 local stoarage to save an Javascript array

Tags: javascript, html

From what i understand, i'll have to save the array as a JSON file and then save that locally using HTML5 local storage. Does anyone have any examples so i can get my head around it. The tutorial showing up from Google don't seem very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be quite straight-forward. Just put a delegate between your code and `localStorage` that converts all values from and to JSON:

```
// conversion functions
var fromJSON = JSON.parse,
    toJSON   = JSON.stringify;

// storage functions
var get = function(key) {
  return fromJSON(localStorage[key]);
};

var set = function(key, value) {
  localStorage[key] = toJSON(value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try CarboStorage. It handles objects automatically, including dates. Filtering is also supported.

http://carbogrid.com/index.php/storage/home